# Vue error telling me variable value is undefined but the image displays correctly so why then the error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I get data from a back end and I load the data inside the onBeforeMount hook like so:

```
onBeforeMount(async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("api/v1/posts/replies/" + replyID + "/");
    reply.value = res.data;
    post.value = reply.value.post;
});
```

In the template I have this image to represent a user:

```
<router-link
    v-if="reply.profile.photo"
    :to="{ path: '/user/' + post.user }"
>
    <div class="userImage">
        <img
            class="userImg"
            :src="'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + reply.profile.photo"
        />
    </div>
</router-link>
```

In the console I have this error pointing to the line :src="‘http://127.0.0.1:8000’ + reply.profile.photo:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $setup.reply.profile is undefined

How am I then supposed to load the data so these errors do not appear? Best of all with the error the user picture displays correctly. I have refreshed many times cleared cache but still the error remains and the picture displays.

Can someone tell me why is this happening please?

Comment: It's possible that `vue` isn't expecting an `async` callback to `onBeforeMount` - so your function is queued and resolved, but Vue doesn't wait for it to finish. This would explain your error, as on the first "load" `reply` doesn't have a value, but then once your `get` finishes `reply` now does have a value, Vue re-renders, and your image is displayed

Comment: But if reply doesn't have a value, the outer `router-link` should not be rendered in the first place because of the `v-if`. Are you sure the error is coming from the `:src` line? If reply is undefined in the beginning, then `v-if="reply.profile.photo"` should throw something like `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`. Can you check if the error is solved by adding a `?` to the `v-if`: `v-if="reply?.profile?.photo"`

Comment: Error goes away with reply?.profile?.photo. I am new to this so what does the question marks do in the statement reply?.profile?.photo please?

Comment: it's called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).